# sound parameter cannot be gotten

Tags: python, django

sound parameter cannot be gotten.I wrote codes

```
def common(request):
    if request.FILES:
        file = request.FILES['sound'].temporary_file_path()
        return HttpResponse('<h1>OK</h1>')
    else:
        file = None
        return HttpResponse('<h1>NG</h1>')
```

I send wav file via POSTMAN like
[image]

Now if I set sound parameter in POSTMAN,always NG is returned.I really cannot understand why this program do so.I print out `request.FILES` so  is printed out.So am I wrong to write the way of writing if-else statement branch?How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove `Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or whatever from the Headers tab. Then upload Postman will automatically insert the multipart/form-data for you.